# Options menu not working properly

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-optionsmenu

I was working in android studio and everything was working fine but suddenly there comes a problem. When i click on the top right options menu buttons the menu don't inflates and app crashes, the menu items works fine when set to `app:showAsAction="always"`  but it crashes when `app:showAsAction="never"`. Also, when i rebuild my previous projects to check the issue then they also have this problem which was not before.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Toolbar toolbare;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.drawer_activity);

        toolbare = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbare);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu_white_24dp);
}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_list_view_type, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.i("info", "In optionsItemSelected");
       switch (item.getItemId()) {
           case R.id.view_type_single:
               NoteFragSingle noteSingle = new NoteFragSingle();
               FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
               fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,
                       android.R.anim.fade_out);
               fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragMent, noteSingle);
               fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
               return true;
           case R.id.view_type_multi:
               NoteFragGrid noteFragGrid = new NoteFragGrid();
               fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
               fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,
                       android.R.anim.fade_out);
               fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragMent, noteFragGrid);
               fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
               return true;

               default:
                   return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
       }

    }
```

**menu_list_view_type.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/view_type_multi"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_view_module_black_24dp"
        android:title="Multi Column View"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/view_type_single"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_view_list_black_24dp"
        android:title="Single Column View"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

app level **build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This **error** shows up every time in current as well as every project which was previously working fine.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
at android.support.v7.view.menu.ListMenuItemView.setTitle(ListMenuItemView.java:127)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.ListMenuItemView.initialize(ListMenuItemView.java:113)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuAdapter.getView(MenuAdapter.java:100)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopup.measureIndividualMenuWidth(MenuPopup.java:160)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.StandardMenuPopup.tryShow(StandardMenuPopup.java:153)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.StandardMenuPopup.show(StandardMenuPopup.java:187)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.showPopup(MenuPopupHelper.java:290)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.tryShow(MenuPopupHelper.java:175)
at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter$OpenOverflowRunnable.run(ActionMenuPresenter.java:803)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

I tried clean and rebuild, invalidate and restart but nothing worked please help me.

**Edit**

**Here is the fragment code**

```
public class NoteFragSingle extends Fragment {
    private NoteAdapter mAdapter;
    RecyclerView rView;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Cursor cursor;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private List<Note> noteList = new ArrayList<Note>();


    public NoteFragSingle() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_note_frag_single, container, false);
        rView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        TextView empty = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.empty_single);
        mAdapter = new NoteAdapter(getActivity(), noteList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        rView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        rView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        rView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
      /*  if(noteList.isEmpty()){
            rView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            empty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            rView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            empty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        */

        try {
            Databasehelper textoDatabaseHelper = new Databasehelper(getActivity());
            db = textoDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            cursor = db.query("NOTES", new String[]{"_id","TITLE", "DESCRIPTION", "DATE"}, null, null, null, null, null);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                do {
                    String Title = cursor.getString(1);
                    String Description = cursor.getString(2);
                    String Date = cursor.getString(3);
                    Note note = new Note(Title, Description, Date);
                    noteList.add(note);
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }while(cursor.moveToNext());

            }
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Cannot retrieve notes. Try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        return  v;
    }



}
```

Comment: where  are you using TextView ??????

Comment: I am not using any TextView

Comment: share your whole code @AnishM

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)  ........error in nullpointerexception in textview........I think problem with your fragment

Comment: @Prem This is my whole code rest is the layout.

Comment: @AnishM where you are seeting **TextView.setText()**

Comment: @AnishM remove **`super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);`**

Comment: share your fragments code

Comment: @AnishM also share code for Fragment

Comment: @Prem There isn't any TextView, I searched this question and someone suggested that it is gradle 3.3 issue and downgrade it to 2.2.3

Comment: @AnishM ,Did you set any TextView in fragment??

Comment: @AnishM for test case remove **`super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);`** from your `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44712605/android-overflow-menu-nullpointerexception-when-clicking-three-dots

Comment: @Prem  I've added the fragment code. I tried removing the `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);` but it didn't worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @AnishM your fragment code is fine just check onecs in **NoteAdapter**

Comment: @Prem The problem is not because of a class I think Since, my previous projects also have this problem which was previously fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling inflation at wrong point. You should do it before calling **super()**. Call it like below.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_list_view_type, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);;
}
```

Comment: On which Api level you are currently ?

Comment: I'm using Api 25

Comment: I just tested you code . Its working fine at my end .Its showing Overflow menu with two items. try to test on lower version may be on Lollipop once .

Comment: which gradle version are you using @ADM

Comment: Mine is 3.3 and  buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

Comment: and plugin version @ADM

Comment: version is  2.3.3.